# Are javax.persistence.Query objects cachable?

Tags: java, multithreading, persistence

I'm writing a stateless EJB.
I had methods like:

```
public String getXxx(final String userId) throws ... {
    final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(...);
    query.setParameter(1, userId);
    return (String)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Can I cache the Query object instantiating it at load time and using it in a multi-thread environment?

```
private static final Query query = em.createNativeQuery(...);
public String getXxx(final String userId) throws ... {
    query.setParameter(1, userId);
    return (String)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. `Query` is created by (and references) a particular `EntityManager` instance which is:

1. Not thread-safe.
2. Should not be held onto for prolonged periods of time.

Answer (score 1):

I think ChssPly76 is right. But you should maybe look at [NamedQueries](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#Named_Queries). Maybe this is something in the direction your looking.

Answer (score 0):

However, you can make the query String itself class-instantiated. This will save you a nanosecond here and there.

Here's a greatly simplified example (I apologize for any syntax or other errors):

```
private static final String sqlMyQuery =
    "SELECT stu FROM Student stu " +
    "WHERE stu.zipCode = ?1 " +
    "AND stu.status = ?2";

public static Student getStudentByZipAndStatus(String zip, int status) {
    Student student = em.createNativeQuery(sqlMyQuery)
        .setParameter(1, zip)
        .setParameter(2, status)
        .getSingleResult();

    return (student);
}
```